# What kind of trouble if using _global in swf for presenter

Tags: flash, global, presenter

I have to transform a lot of swf to using them in Presenter.
They are old (AS1) and was developed with a lot of "_root" everywhere ("_root" don't work in Presener).

So my idea was to set a global variable like this :

`_global.myUniqueVariable = this;//on the first image of the scene, this = _level0 or _root`

and to replace _root by _global.myUniqueVariable.

But in the documentation of Presenter 7 (I'm working on the 8), Adobe alert to not use _root, _level#, stage AND _global. But I tried and it worked.

So, what kind of problem could occur if I use it. The only trouble I can imagine is to overwrite a variable of Presenter (but with a very specific name it will not append).

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

If you load swf1 into another swf2 with loadMovie command, and swf1 and swf2 compiled for different player versions, there will be different _globals. And debugger may not show that fact.

If you loaded some swf's into different levels or movies and that swfs coordinates with "single data exchange point _global", it may not work...